# How to read independent indented JSON objects from a file (JSON Lines but indented)?

Tags: python, json, indentation

I have a massive file storing JSON objects next to each other which was supposed to be in  [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) format, but I made the big mistake of storing them indented (hence each object taking multiple lines instead of one).

It has this format (notice that `,` is missing between objects):

```
{
    "contributors": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "created_at": "Mon Sep 21 11:51:09 +0000 2020",
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [],
        "symbols": []
    }
}
{
    "contributors": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "created_at": "Mon Sep 21 11:51:09 +0000 2020",
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [],
        "symbols": []
    }
}
```

All the project is made to work with non indented files (one JSON per line), and my idea was to transform this big JSON file to unindented format, but I'm struggling to find a way to read the file.
The code I tried to transform it is:

```
import json
import sys
import os

FILE_INPUT='PathToTheBigFile'
FILE_OUTPUT='PathToConvertedFile'

tweets_list = []

for line in open(FILE_INPUT, 'r', encoding='utf-8'):
    tweets_list.append(json.loads(line))

with open(FILE_OUTPUT, 'a') as outfile:
    for tweet in tweets_list:
        outfile.write(json.dumps(tweet) + '\n')
```

And it works fine with non-indented files (it basically copies the file) but with the indented file this `JSONDecodeError` is raised:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: 
    Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

I have tried to do it in Python and also thought about doing it with Linux and tr commands or something like that, but I haven't found a way. I may try with other languages.

Any suggestion about how to do it?

Comment: Your indented JSON is invalid. There should be a comma `,` after the closing curly brace `}` on line 9. The JSON decoder doesn't differentiate between indented and unindented formats **at all**, as long as the formatting is valid. You must have made some other changes when you indented it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the **full text** of the JSONDecodeError *as text* (not an image), as you'll probably be able to figure out the problem from there.

Comment: @MattDMo That's invalid as well, if the two objects are contained in a list. The `json` module expects a *single* JSON value, and two juxtaposed objects isn't one.

Comment: @MattDMo the problem persists with only one JSON

Comment: "...one JSON per line" -- so not JSON but [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have 2 objects next to each other in your JSON string/file.  If you could add a comma between them (and wrap the whole thing in `[]`), then you could parse it as an array of objects.

Try something like this when reading in your file:

```
import re

with open(FILE_INPUT, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json_data = re.sub(r"}\s*{", "},{", file.read())
    tweets_list.extend(json.loads("[" + json_data + "]"))
```

Then, when writing your file, you should be saving it as an array of objects, instead of one object per-line.  There's no reason to be calling `json.dumps` more than once.

```
with open(FILE_OUTPUT, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps(tweets_list))
```

Note I'm using `'w'`, so it's overwriting the file.  You'll have you read in the *whole* file first so you can append to the array and write the whole file back out.

---

If you are gonna be appending data to a file, and reading that file back in again, I'd suggest trying something like `csv` instead of `json`.  You can easily append lines to a `csv` file without worry about parsing it back in later.  Or maybe even an `xml` file could work here too.

Comment: I see, this problem appeared because I store the data with json.dumps and append a \n at the end, so the format isn't really JSON and it's just a file containing multiple JSON objects, one per line. The problem I have now is that I cannot edit the file I already have (202991424 lines), so I'm working on a way to transform it.

Comment: @CarlosSoler The 1st code block should be able to read the file and use a regex to add commas between the objects and then if you wrap that in `[]` you should be able to parse the while thing as a big list of dicts.  Then you can loop over that and write that to the file as you want.

Comment: @CarlosSoler I've updated question to match what I think you want... Please confirm the edit so Rocket can adjust the answer if needed.

Comment: @CarlosSoler Are you just trying to make a one-shot script to convert the file?

Comment: @Carlos: If you can change the format so it does not indent the output — which should be easy if you're using `json.dumps()` — then you can read the input in a line at a time and `json.load()` it (and append the result to a list).

Comment: @martineau Yes, thank for the edit and the additions to the body, Do you think "independent indented JSON objects from a file" would be better? I'm pretty sure I'll have it resolved now. The solution you gave me is exactly how normally I store the data, but I used `json.dumps()` indentation to be able to understand the JSON objects and forgot about it before storing a big file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I used `sed "s/^}$/},/g"` to add all the commas, then added the brackets and finally deleted the last comma.

Comment: @Carlos: Yes, it think it would be better — it's actually a semi-formal standard format called [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) and very common in the Lunix world. Not indenting will also make the file a little smaller.